# Javascript css two styles at once depending on boolean "completed" and "school"

Tags: javascript, css

I have created a "to do list" that appropriately puts a style on the text for an item in a list when a certain button has been clicked

```
<li className = {`todo-item ${todo.completed ? "completed" : ""}`}>
     {text} 
</li>
```

In a corresponding css file, I have the following

```
 .completed {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
```

Now, I want to implement another button (example: "school"). When the school button is pressed, the text would turn a different style (like yellow). In my css I have

```
  .school {
    color: yellow;
  }
```

How can I make it so that when I click on the school button, it becomes yellow, and when I click on both the completed and school button, it becomes a faded yellow with a line through?
What I have tried is putting the todo.school ? "school" : "" inside of the first segment of code, but to no success.

Thank you for any help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: So add one more ternary `todo-item ${todo.completed ? "completed" : ""} ${todo.school ? "school" : ""}`

Comment: For even more control, back at the CSS level, you could do something like `.completed.school {opacity: .5; color: yellow; text-decoration: line-through;}`  CSS reads top down, just like JavaScript.  The more granular you define it the better for those particular scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `classList` property of an element to do this. It has a `toggle()` method which allows you to add and remove a class name on an element independently from any other class names that are currently set on it.

```js
completed.addEventListener('click', () => listItem.classList.toggle('completed'));
school.addEventListener('click', () => listItem.classList.toggle('school'));
```

```css
body {
  background: darkgrey;
}

.completed {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.school {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="listItem">
    Go and have some dinner
  </li>
</ul>

<button id="completed">completed</button>
<button id="school">school</button>
```